# What does this "Killed" error mean in Python?

Tags: python, image, pickle, kill

I have no understanding of what happened here. Could somebody please explain why Python3.4 "killed" this script:

```
def __init__(self, target, data_flatten, data, 
              tf, hlf, white, robert, sobel, scharr):
    self.data_flatten = data_flatten
    self.target = target
    self.data = data
    self.tf = tf
    self.hlf = hlf
    self.white = white
    self.robert = robert
    self.sobel = sobel
    self.scharr = scharr

with open('PI0_Electron_Mixed_2000.pickle', 'wb') as output:
    pickle.dump(PI0_Electron_Mixed_2000, output)
```

Here is the output when I ran the script in my terminal:

```
[jdoe@edne01 ~]$ cd PycharmProjects/ImageReader
[jdoe@edne01 ImageReader]$ python3.4 DataCompiler.py 
Killed
[jdoe@edne01 ImageReader]$
```

So what the hell happened, can anybody explain?

Comment: might be a memoryerror, it is from your OS not python

Comment: I've experienced this in the past. In my case, it was indeed a memoryerror.

Comment: You can probably confirm by checking your syslog or whatever the equivalent is on your os

Answer (score -3):

This happened for me too while reading large files. You can try rebooting your system and this should stop.